# shell script does not read my input line by line

Tags: loops, sh

I have bourne shell script like

```
#!/bin/sh

 for i in $(cat /etc/hosts)

   do

    echo $i

  done
```

when I run this script every word in /etc/hosts file printed into different line, I mean if the file's line are like

```
127.0.0.1 localhost

10.0.0.1  fenasi
```

the output likes

```
 127.0.0.1

 localhost

 10.0.0.1

 fenasi
```

Is there any way to read the file line by line and print out as line like in original. I need this solution for also processing command line inputs

Thanks and regards

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably that the IFS (Input Field Separators) variable include spaces as separators (or is unset, which amounts to the same thing.)

The following is closer to what you want :

```
#!/bin/sh
IFS="
"
for i in $(cat /etc/hosts)
  do
    echo $i
  done
```

Here, we use only newline as field separator, so each row will be considered as a field.